# Control overriding the condition (main), after ISR completion on dspic33ep

Tags: c, overriding, interrupt, microchip, isr

I'm trying to rotate an DC motor in clock wise and counter clockwise direction using
two push buttons(there are three actually and another is button3 to enter manual mode) and
also there is flag attached to shaft of the motor, which is detected by inductive sensor.
here are my steps,

1. so at first, I'll generate some delay based on 4 dip switch values
2. after delay, the motor starts rotating in CW direction until flag is detected
   (both this and above steps happens in `main` function)
3. once flag is found, an interrupt is generated (INT2) and it stops and starts the motor
   in CCW direction for 5 sec and stops it (this step happens in ISR).
4. Now the control comes from ISR to `main()` and waits in `while(1)` to enter manual mode
5. so when button3 is pressed for 3 sec, than we enter manual mode by calling its
   function Manual_mode().
6. in manual mode function we'll rotate motor in CW or CCW direction by press and holding
   button1 or button2 respectively.

issue: everything is working fine but when control return from ISR to infinite loop and when
I enter manual mode, the motor starts automatically by itself(in CW dir), before pressing button1
or button2.

board : dsPIC33EP512GM604
using MPLABx with xC16 compiler.

**Main function**

```
    void main(void) 
    {
        
        SYSTEM_Initialize();
        LED_initialize();
        switch_initialize();
        configureINT();
        
                    //start_motor:
                    
              if(DIP1_SW == 0 && DIP2_SW == 0 && DIP3_SW == 0 && DIP4_SW == 0)  
                 {
                
                    D8_LED = 1;
                      
                       __delay_ms(2000);
                    TP6 = 1;  
                    TP5 = 0; 
                    __delay_ms(2000);
                     L2 = 0;
                     L6 = 1; 
                  
                 }
            
                   
            else if (DIP1_SW == 1 && DIP2_SW == 0 && DIP3_SW == 0 && DIP4_SW == 0)
            {
                     __delay_ms(15000);
                    
                     D8_LED = 1;
                      
                       __delay_ms(2000);
                    TP6 = 1;  
                    TP5 = 0; 
                    __delay_ms(2000);
                     L2 = 0;
                     L6 = 1;
                   
            }
                   
            else    
            {
                 __delay_ms(225000);
                    
                     D8_LED = 1;
                      
                       __delay_ms(2000);
                    TP6 = 1;  
                    TP5 = 0; 
                    __delay_ms(2000);
                     L2 = 0;
                     L6 = 1;
         
            }
                     
        while(1)
        {               
          if (MOTVALID_PRESSED == isMOTVALIDpressed_3sec()) // if MOTVALID pressed for 3SEC, than 
                                                               enter Manual Mode. 
            {
                Manual_mode();
                   
            }     
             
        }
        
    }



void Manual_mode ()
{
            D7_LED = 1;
            __delay_ms(500);
            D7_LED = 0;
            __delay_ms(500);
            D7_LED = 1;
            __delay_ms(500);
            D7_LED = 0;
            __delay_ms(500);
            
          while(1)
           {
              if (!MOTCW) // Turn the motor while button is pressed
               {
                  D8_LED = 1;
                   __delay_ms(2000);
                  TP6 = 1;  
                  TP5 = 0; 
                   __delay_ms(2000);
                   L2 = 0;
                   L6 = 1;
                   break;
               }
            
                 else if (!MOTCCW)
                    {
           
                        D8_LED = 1;
                       __delay_ms(2000);
                       TP6 = 0;  
                       TP5 = 0; 
                       __delay_ms(2000);
                       L2 = 1;
                       L6 = 0;
                       break;
                    } 
            
                        else 
                      { 
                       D8_LED = 0;
                       D7_LED = 1;
               
                       TP5 = 1;
                       TP6 = 0;
                       L2 = 0;
                       L6 = 0;
                       break;
                      }
            }
        
}
```

**ISR function**

```
void __attribute__ ((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _INT2Interrupt(void) 
{
    if (IFS1bits.INT2IF == 1)
    {          
               INTCON2bits.GIE = 0;
               D8_LED = 0;
               D7_LED = 0;
               
                TP5 = 1;
                TP6 = 0;
                 L2 = 0;
                 L6 = 0;
                 
                 D7_LED = 1;
                 
                 __delay_ms(1000);  // 1 SEC DELAY FOR STOPPING MOTOR 
                 
                  D7_LED = 0;
                  D8_LED = 1;
                  
                __delay_ms(2000); // TURN THE MOTOR IN REVERSE DIRECTION FOR 5SEC
                TP6 = 0;  
                TP5 = 0; 
                __delay_ms(2000);
                 L2 = 1;
                 L6 = 0;
                 
                 __delay_ms(5000);
                 
                 D7_LED = 1;
                 D8_LED = 0;
                 
                 TP5 = 1;
                 TP6 = 0;
                 L2 = 0;
                 L6 = 0;
              
    }

 IFS1bits.INT2IF = 0;
}
```

I think I'm missing something. thanks.

Comment: Normally it's not a really good idea to put long delays in your ISR. A ISR should be as short as possible.

Comment: hey @Mike thank you for the heads-up. as you said, I ran the code by removing delays ( that 5 sec) in the ISR but the problem persists. please let me know if you have  something.